# chrome crash with method call of java in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I am trying to use a java application in html5 and javascript, but Chrome always crashes when I try the following:

In the **html5** document I have this:

```
<FORM>
<INPUT type="button" value="call JAVA" onClick = "test()">
</FORM>

<object name="application" type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550" >
<param name="code" value="loader"/>
<param name="java_arguments" value="-Djnlp.packEnabled=true"/>
</object>
```

In the **javascript** file I use this function(the onclick test()-function)

```
function test() {
    var app = document.getElementById("applet_test");
    alert("Screen Dimension\r\n  width:" +
         app.getScreenWidth() + " height:" +
         app.getScreenHeight() );
}
```

And finally this is the **applet_test.java** file:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class applet_test extends Applet 
{   public int getScreenWidth() {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
      }
      public int getScreenHeight() {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
      }
    public void main(String [] args) {

    }
}
```

Does anybody know why this won't work? Eclipse is also complaining about the use of an applet in an html5-document:

```
Element (applet) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5
```

Could this cause the troubles and if so, how can you get the same result with an  element?

Comment: I added the warning to my post

Comment: `Element (applet) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5`  That is odd, given the HTML snippet uses an `object` element.  But that aside, the best solution is to embed the applet using the `deployJava.js` mentioned in the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  It is designed to work in whatever browser it is loaded in. It checks the user has the minimum Java needed to run the applet (helps them update, if not) then writes whatever element in whatever form that is expected by that (version of) that browser.  Oh, and it is 'invisible' to validation services.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson  Great info. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @rickz `deployJava.js` is just one of the great little tweaks introduced for applets over the last few years. People regularly say "applets died years ago", but that is obviously not what Sun thought throughout their ..sunset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><FORM>
<head>
<script>
function test() {
    var app = document.applet_test;
    alert("Screen Dimension\r\n  width:" + app.getScreenWidth()
      + " height:" + app.getScreenHeight());
}
</script>
<body>
<INPUT type="button" value="call JAVA"
   onClick = "test()">
</FORM>
<object name="applet_test" type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550" >
<param name="code" value="loader.class"/>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that code, I got it working with this. Now I see the java loading screen, but it doesn't stop with loading. Maybe it is because I give a size to the object while there isn't showed anything. It could also be a problem with the java file itself (I updated my version with the current one)

Comment: What do you mean "but it doesn't stop with loading" ?

Comment: this image is shown while loading:http://www.google.be/imgres?imgurl=http://www.w-uh.com/images/0301/Java_loading.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.w-uh.com/posts/090629a.html&h=167&w=158&sz=4&tbnid=UVqoIWja6rt6GM:&tbnh=96&tbnw=91&zoom=1&docid=uT8Zn-OCAbdDlM&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=BgR1T43eEMaS0QWimeC5DQ&ved=0CE0Q9QEwBQ&dur=237 and stays

Comment: It goes away for me. Did you try with height="1" width="1" ?  Also, you can try using style to absolute position off the screen somewhere.

Comment: thank you for the advice, now it isn't showed anymore, the only problem that is remaining is that de methods of the java class aren't found yet. I get the message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'getScreenWidth'

Comment: Is the code at the top your current code ? If yes, then change name="application" to name="applet_test"  and change public class applet_test extends Applet   to  public class Loader extends Applet   and change <param name="code" value="Loader"/>  This way Loader is the  Java name  and applet_test is the javascript name.

Answer (score 1):

Change   var app = document.getElementById("applet_test");  to

```
var app = document.applet_test;
```

> Eclipse is also complaining about the use of an applet in an html5-document.

Probably because the applet tag is deprecated. Look at bottom of
https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/HTML5_APPLETS/

Comment: The link you gave me certainly helpfull, but it doesnet solve all my problems. I changed my applet to a more general object and I added a the main procedure for my java class. The only thing that can't be found in the example is how to invoke methods from that java class in javascript. (I edited my post with my changes)

Comment: *"The link you gave me certainly helpfull, but it doesnet solve all my problems."*  At SO, it is supposed to be 'one answer per question'.  Please don't expect us to sort the '15 things' wrong with this applet in a single question.  Get one thing working at a time, mark an answer correct, then move on to the next part.

Comment: **From the link:**  *"NEW WAY: Java Applet in HTML5 (uses object tag)"*  Actually, for some time Sun/Oracle has provided the `deployJava.js` mentioned in the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  Use that instead of hard-coding either `applet` or `object` elements.